# Summing N number A1 + A4 + A7

Tags: c#

I am trying to sum different numbers in C#  +3 of the inputs 
ex:

N numbers are written in console

```
a1: 3
a2: 5
a3: 6
a4:-3
a5: 5
```

I want it to sum `A1 + A4 + A7` (if there is `A7`) and so on.

I am kind of a newbie with C# and was unable to find a solution on how to save the numbers when you don't know how many numbers will be written.

Comment: Please pick **exactly** one programming language and after that produce a [mcve] in **that** language.

Comment: The problem is not specified clearly enough. User either needs to enter the number `N` before entering rows, or there should be a way to indicate that the input has ended (e.g. empty line). Please post your existing code, otherwise it's hard to tell which part you are stuck on.

Comment: Tip: Look to use a dynamic storage type, such as `List<int>`

Answer (score 1):

You may use dynamic collection `List<int>` and iterate with `for` loop:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(3);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(6);
list.Add(-3);
list.Add(5);

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if(i % 3 == 0) // sum every third number
    {
        sum += list[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you increment the loop counter by 3 you do not need the `if` statement. I.e. `i += 3`.

Answer (score 0):

For storing unknown number of elements, you should use a collection, a list for example.

Now, depending how you input the numbers in console you could add them to the list in two ways, either give one number in each line, or just input all numbers in a single line, code for the 2nd case:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
string[] strings = Console.ReadLine().Split();
foreach (var number in strings)
{
   list.Add(int.Parse(number));
}
```

Then you need to add elements in the list in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your numbers line by line you may avoid storing them all into `List`:

```
var lineNumber = 0;
var sum = 0;
while (true)
{
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        break;
    if (lineNumber++ % 3 == 0)
        sum += int.Parse(line);
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

This code summarize each third row until user enter empty line